# How to calculate limit in a quotient function

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate the limit of the following function:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1} -\sqrt[2]{x} }{x-1}$$

I've tried to use the following formula: $(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ without any success. Is there anything that I'm missing?

I can't use L'Hôpital rule.

Comment: The numerator and the denominator both tend to $0$ as $x$ tends to $1$. So the limit is in indeterminate form $0/0$. Try L'Hospital's rule and see where you get with it?

Comment: Hav you gone through https://math.stackexchange.com/tour ?

Comment: Great to see that all the answers are correct and downvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1} -\sqrt{x} }{x-1}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}-1- (\sqrt{x}-1) }{x-1}=$$
$$=\frac{2(x+1)}{\sqrt[3]{(2x^2-1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\rightarrow\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{6}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Basic limit laws and standard limit $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}\tag{1}$$ suffice here.

We have
\begin{align*}
L&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}-\sqrt{x}}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}-1}{x-1}-\frac{x^{1/2}-1^{1/2}}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}-1}{2x^2-1-1}\cdot 2(x+1)-\frac{1}{2}\\
&=4\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{t^{1/3}-1^{1/3}}{t-1}-\frac{1}{2}\text{ (putting }t=2x^2-1) \\
&=4\cdot\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{5}{6}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Notice $\lim_{x\to\:1}\left(\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}-\sqrt{x}\right)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\:1}\left(x-1\right)=0$

Thus, $\lim_{x\to\:1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}-\sqrt{x}}{x-1}\right)=\frac{0}{0}$. Which is also known as "indeterminate form". In such situations, we apply L'Hopital's rule, as follows:

By differentiating the numerator and denominator, we get:
$$\lim_{x\to\:1}\left(\frac{\frac{4x}{3\left(2x^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{1}{2x^{\frac{1}{2}}}}{1}\right)$$

Tidy this up:
$$\lim_{x\to\:1}\left(\frac{8x\sqrt{x}-3\left(2x^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{6\sqrt{x}\left(2x^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)$$

Set $x=1$:

$$\frac{8\cdot\:1\cdot\sqrt{1}-3\left(2\cdot\:1^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{6\sqrt{1}\left(2\cdot\:1^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

Evaluate the above, and hence the limit is $5/6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $a=\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}$ and $b =\sqrt[2]{x}$, then $a^6 = (2x^2-1)^2=4x^4-4x^2+1$ and $b^6 = x^3$. Then $$a^6-b^6 = 4x^4-x^3-4x^2+1 $$ $$=(x-1)(4x^3+3x^2-x-1)$$

$$=(x-1)(4b^6+3b^4-b^2-1)$$

Thus
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1} -\sqrt[2]{x} }{x-1}=\lim_{a,b \rightarrow 1}\frac{(a-b)(4b^6+3b^4-b^2-1)}{a^6-b^6}$$ $$=\lim_{a,b \rightarrow 1}\frac{4b^6+3b^4-b^2-1}{a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5}={5\over 6}$$

Answer (score -1):

With $x=y+1$, you get
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x^2-1}-\sqrt{x}}{x-1} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2(y+1)^2-1}-\sqrt{y+1}}{y}$$

You have to compute the limit of this quantity when $y$ tends to $0$.

Now 
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2(y+1)^2-1}-\sqrt{y+1}}{y} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2y^2 + 4y +1}-\sqrt{y+1}}{y} = \frac{1+ \frac{1}{3}(2y^2+4y) + o(y)-1- \frac{1}{2}y + o(y)}{y} $$

i.e. 
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2(y+1)^2-1}-\sqrt{y+1}}{y} = \frac{5}{6} + o(1)$$

So the limit is equal to 
$$\frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: What is that $o(y)$?

Comment: A function which is tends to $0$ faster that $y \mapsto y$... This is a very common and elementary notation, but I guess you have never heard yet of series expansion. See here for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations

Comment: @havakok By the way, downvoting because you don't have the required knowledge to understand an answer is not very fair.

Comment: I did not downvote. I do think, however, that using a function such as $o(y)$ without defining or expanding on it. $o$ can be many things. The transition you made using $o$ is still not clear to me. Your answer is original, though, it is not written well. I do think you deserv a down vote.

Comment: Writing $\sqrt{1+y} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}y + o(y)$, when $y \rightarrow 0$, is clear for everyone who knows series expansions. If it is not your case, no problem of course ; but it's not because you don't understand it that my answer is "not written well".

Comment: Well, apparently at least two other users agree that this is not a well-written answer. I just tried to give you insight as of why.